# Angular $observe with $apply

Tags: angularjs

Im currently observing attribute values using `$observe` inside a directive, as I change the value of the attribute the callback is called, when I then change a `$scope` variable it isn't "updated" and I figured this is because I need to use `$apply`, when invoking `$apply` I get the error `$rootScope:inprog` which seems to be because of the `$observe`?

Simply, how do I update a $scope variable from inside an $observe?

My code (Coffee):

```
App.directive "reactiveButton", () ->
  directive = {}

  directive.restrict = "E"
  directive.scope =
    translateId: '@translateId'
    loadingIndicator: '@loadingIndicator'
  directive.templateUrl = App.Base.concat("directive/reactive-button.html")
  directive.link = ($scope, $elements, $attrs) ->  

    $attrs.$observe 'translateId', (value) ->
      $scope.$apply () ->
        $scope.translateId = value

    $attrs.$observe 'loadingIndicator', (value) ->
      $scope.loadingIndicator = Boolean value

  return directive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
directive.scope =
  translateId: '@translateId'
  loadingIndicator: '@loadingIndicator'
```

This part tells AngularJS to create an *isolated* scope. AngularJS will create watchers for the attributes of this directive for those properties. It will update the scope whenever those attributes change. You don't have to observe them.

```
    App.directive "reactiveButton", () ->
      directive = {}

      directive.restrict = "E"
      directive.scope =
        translateId: '@translateId'
        loadingIndicator: '@loadingIndicator'
      directive.templateUrl = App.Base.concat("directive/reactive-button.html")
      return directive
```

You're directive doesn't need a link function, because there isn't anything else for it to do (at this point). The template `reactive-button.html` will still work with the `translateId` and `loadingIndicator` bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Your $observe block is redundant in this example. You've already got an isolate scope that's set up to assign translateId to the scope, so you can remove it.

What do you mean by "isn't updated"?

Inside reactive-button.html, you should be able to see the value of translateId by putting this somewhere: {{translateId}}

^ That should change to reflect your attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `$apply` your scope in an `$observe` listener: it will already be triggered during a digect cycle.

Updating as you did should be enough, please reproduce and explain us the problem you have when doing so.